# Extending home partition capacity on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I have Ubuntu 20.04 virtually installed on vmware workstation 12 with windows 10 as the host.

I made a mistake on installation process and allocate just 5GB to home partition.

After installing several packages it reached its limit and ran out of capacity.

Here is a screenshot of what I have on my disk:
[image]

Could you please guide me how to increase the capacity of home directory to have 25GB more?

I did some research but couldn't find anything that suits my problem since I have unallocated space on a non-adjacent partition.

I am a beginner Linux user, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You also didn't allocate enough space to `/`. This is an even bigger problem. If your disk space is at such a premium that you have to be miserly about it, then you should not be creating a separate home partition. Reinstall and allocate at **least** 25 GB for Ubuntu. This is the bare minimum system requirement for Ubuntu desktop. It would be wise to allocate more than the minimum if you can afford it.

Comment: @Nmath OK thanks, I didn't want to reinstall I thought there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need to boot your VM with live media that contains the GParted application. The Ubuntu install media is perfect. Here are the steps:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose.
2. Boot the live media, choose “Try Ubuntu” if using the Ubuntu install media.
3. Start GParted. I recommend you reduce the size  of sda1 first. You can recover about 5GB there. Complete that operation.
4. Next you need to resize sda2 so that it extends from sda1 to the end of the drive. Complete that operation.
5. You now need to decide how much space to give to sda5 and sda6. Move sda6 all the way to the right and sda5 all the way to the left. Share out the space according to your decision. You might want to complete this as several steps completing each as you go.
6. Shut down and reboot. Should be fine. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time, thats a big help!